# Custom Breakpoints not working in Nuxt with Vuetify

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm just trying to put custom breakpoints in the Vuetify options of an almost-barebones Nuxt install, and for some reason it just doesn't register.

Repo : https://github.com/lekevoid/test-nuxt

Install on Netlify : https://ecstatic-pare-528d74.netlify.app/

The other options, like the "light theme by default", work fine, but the breakpoints thresholds seem to not want to register.

```
// nuxt.config.js

vuetify: {
    optionsPath: "./vuetify.config.js",
},
```

```
// vuetify.config.js

export default {
    ...
    customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
    breakpoint: {
        thresholds: {
            xs: 0,
            sm: 576,
            md: 768,
            lg: 992,
            xl: 1088,
        },
    },
    ...
}
```

```
// assets/variables.scss

$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1088px
);
```

With all that, I would expect the breakpoints to be replaced or extended... But when I inspect the .container element, it still seems to adopt the default breakpoints :

[image]

I tried deleting the .nuxt folder and restarting the server, to no avail.

What am I missing ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I have had the exact same issue. So far I haven't been able to find a solution, if you output your break points, do they show the correct/expected values? console.log(`sm breakpoint value -> ${this.$vuetify.breakpoint.thresholds.sm}`);              console.log(`md breakpoint value -> ${this.$vuetify.breakpoint.thresholds.md}`);
        console.log(`lg breakpoint value -> ${this.$vuetify.breakpoint.thresholds.lg}`); Because mine does.